# is the erratic behaviour and the following related? entering "www.mydomain" instead of "mydomain" sends me to my other site under same IP

Tags: nginx, godaddy

The purpose of this question is to mention two things that I cant understand. I want to ask if they are related, in order to know if I should contact the domain vendor or not.

I currently have one IP and I'm using Nginx to serve two sites:

- [ai-friendly.com](http://ai-friendly.com) (a domain that works fine)
- [tictactoe-neural.net](http://tictactoe-neural.net) (a domain that behaves erratically)

Erratic behaviour:
Almost a week has passed since I set up the latter with the following configuration
(GoDaddy conf., translated from Spanish). Nevertheless, sometimes entering "tictactoe-neural.net" in Chrome directs me to GoDaddy.com (the company that sold me the domain).

Another problem:
Entering [www.tictactoe-neural.net](http://www.tictactoe-neural.net) (instead of [tictactoe-neural.net](http://tictactoe-neural.net)) directs me to ai-friendly.com; I dont understand if that is an Nginx directive, a matter of one domain having been set up before the other, something related to the mentioned domain vendor, or another thing.

I know I should contact the vendor about the erratic behaviour, but dont know if the second item ("another problem") should be mentioned too.

GoDaddy conf

```
Type    Name    Value   TTL Actions
A   @   67.205.140.247  1 hora  Modify
A   @   Parked  600 seconds Modify
CNAME   www @   1 hour  Modify
CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com 1 hour  Modify
NS  @   ns01.domaincontrol.com  1 hour  
NS  @   ns02.domaincontrol.com  1 hour  
SOA @   Main server name: ns01.domaincontrol.com.   1 hour
```

Nginx configuration file.

```
server {
    server_name ai-friendly.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / { try_files $uri @app; }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:5000;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 180;
    }
}

server {
    server_name tictactoe-neural.net;
    root /app-tictactoe;
}
```

Comment: regarding your second question, try setting all the domains that redirect to your site as server_name variants.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan thank you as that fixed the "weird" redirecting; now www.tictactoe-neural.net redirects to GoDaddy (the Domain vendor).

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS records tell the story. You have two A record entries for the root of the domain - one pointing to “Parked” and one to an IP (presumably your web server). WWW is created as a CNAME that points to @, or the root.

Remove the “parked” entry so it doesn’t create conflicts, as you actually have a web server.

Comment: This answer shows the relation between both problems. I have done what is advised and after some prudential time I expect to mark it as Accepted.